# Why my channel message send code isn't working?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to send a message at a specific hour on my discord bot but my code isn't working.
I get a "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined" error.
Send part isn't working, i don't know why. I used the same send code elsewhere but it works there. The code i am using is like this. It was saying message is unidentified before i wrote 'message' in function so i solved it like that. I am a beginner so take it easy on me! Please help, thanks!

```
    var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var scheduleFunction = schedule.scheduleJob('00 19 * * *', function(message) {
    message.channel.send('test!');
});
```

Comment: What channel are you expecting the code to send a message to? It seems like you want it to send it to the same channel as `message`, but what is `message`? *Which Discord message* is it supposed to be? You need to be able to describe exactly how the bot should behave, with no ambiguity like there is here.

Comment: i want it to just send the "test!" message to a general channel when the time comes

Comment: "a general channel" is, again, ambiguous. How does the bot choose the general channel? In programming it won't just make a guess and pick a random channel, or know to pick a channel named "general" without you telling it to do exactly that. You have to pick a specific channel to receive the messages, get its ID, and tell the bot to send the message *there* specifically, as Lioness answered below.

Comment: i did what lioness said but it still says "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `message` doesn't refer to a specific message and is thus coming back undefined. Instead, use

```js
var channel = <ID of channel you want the message to be sent to>
client.channels.cache.get(channel).send('test!'):
```

Comment: still says "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined"

Comment: @blur what did you set `channel` to?

Comment: Oh it worked thanks!!! i just forgot some backticks

Comment: Glad I could help 